Prove that $x\sin x $ is continuous for all $x \in \mathbb R$ using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity
Prove that $x\sin x $ is continuous for all $x \in \mathbb R$, using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity.
I tried to do this but I get stuck at one point.
My attempt:
Let $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ and assume $0<|x - x_0|<\delta$
Now consider the following
$$\begin{align}|x\sin x - x_0\sin x_0| &= |x \sin x - x \sin x_0 + x \sin x_0 - x_0 \sin x_0|\\ &\leq |x||\sin x - \sin x_0| +|\sin x_0||x-x_0| \\ &\leq2|x| + |x-x_0|\end{align}$$
And here is where I'm stuck, obviously $|x-x_0|$ is bound by $\delta$, but I'm not sure how to find a bound for $|x|$, any hints would be appreciated.

The upper bound you have found for $|x\sin x-x_0\sin x_0|$ is not tight enough; if $x=10$, say, then $2|x|+|x-x_0|$ will be $\ge10$, and so you won't be able to show that is is $<\varepsilon$ for arbitrary $\varepsilon$. The issue, I think, is in the final line: while it is true that $|x||\sin x-\sin x_0|\le 2|x|$, the upper bound $2|x|$ is far too crude.

As a sort of "cheat": if you look at any analysis book that proves that the limit of $f\cdot g$ is the limit of $f$ times the limit of $g$ (provided these limits exist), then the bounds given to you in the proof can be specialised to this case.

You should use the continuity of sin x

You can also use the fact that $|\sin x - \sin y| \leq |x-y|$, which you can prove using the trig factorization formula.

@Joe ah I see, nice. thanks!

Let $\epsilon>0$. Put $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ If $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|x\sin(x)-y\sin(y)|=|x\sin(x)-ysin(x)+y\sin(x)-y\sin(y)|\leq |x-y|+|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|\leq 2|x-y|\leq \epsilon$.
